# Android Studio 2021.1.1.23 error after initializing first project

Tags: android

I am an absolute beginner with Android Studio, I have recently installed android studio bumblebee (version 2021.1.1.1.23) on my machine. After initializing my first project it shows me many error on the MainActivity.java code file and in activity_main.xml file. It does not show the default Hello World text view on the layout screen even the view is present in the constraint layout. The constraint layout seems to be not working as well. I have looked for so many things but nothing worked for me.

MainActivity.java

[image]

activity_main.xml

[image]

Layout View

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.